# How to set PhantomJS's ViewPort Size in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, web-scraping, phantomjs

I'm working on a project in VBA with Selenium, and I've been trying to set the size of the virtual "window" phantomJS simulates (since it's headless) so that a website loads correctly, since it relies on window size to reorganize css elements in a grid.

I need it to be 1920*1080 in resolution. I'm pretty sure it's just about changing the viewportSize property using arguments, but I'm not sure how to specify this particular one in VBA. I haven't seen any post mentioning how to do it in VBA, so I thought I'd ask here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [this](https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/blob/8a2cde358d2bc06e3014aca2c8d427bc61188a1b/Examples/VBScript/CompareRendering(PhantomJS).vbs) has an example on how to add the screen size.

```
    Set driver = CreateObject("Selenium.PhantomJSDriver")

    'Open Google search UK
    driver.Get "https://www.google.co.uk"

    'Set the window's size in pixels 
    driver.Window.SetSize 1024, 768

    'Capture the rendering with a 500ms delay
    Set imageA = driver.TakeScreenshot(500)
```